# List of Strings to List of Integers?

Tags: java

I was wondering if the following code converts a list with string values to a list of integer values?

Example of what I want :  `['14','15','67']` ---> `[14,15,67]`

```
    String s = strLine;
    List myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
    List<Integer> intList =  myList;
```

Or do I need to iterate over it using a for loop?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see what happens :).

Comment: Spoiler; It won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Java keeps a tight ship.  You need to try and parse the `String`s into integers:

```
List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
for (String s : strList) {
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Comment: @VBCPP Thanks, amended, tight ship indeed.